# Points $\alpha_n$ of $A$ over the $m_n$-th layer in a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-ext. of $K$, where $A$ is an Ab. var. and $m_n$ is strictly increasing

Tags: nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, galois-theory

I have the following setting:

1.) A Galois extension of number fields $K\hookrightarrow L$, with $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)=\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. In my terminology, number field does not imply finiteness over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K\hookrightarrow {K}_{{{p}^{n}}}\hookrightarrow L$ be such that $\operatorname{Gal}({K}_{{{p}^{n}}}/K)=\mathbb{Z}/{{p}^{n}}\cdot \mathbb{Z}$.

2.) An Abelian variety (in my case: a modular Jacobian or an elliptic curve) A, defined over $K$, such that $A(K_{{p}^{n}})$ is finitely generated, but $A(L)$ is not. Furthermore, we assume $A(K)$ has nonzero rank and $A(L)$ has finite torsion.

Does that alone imply the existence of a strictly increasing sequence $\left({m}_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $m_{1}\geq 1$ and a family of nontorsion points ${{\alpha}_{n}}\in {A({{K}_{{{p}^{{m}_{n}}}}})}$ and a natural number $t\geq 1$ such that:

A.) $\alpha_{n+1}\notin A({{K}_{{{p}^{{m}_{n}}}}})$ for all but finitely many $n$.

B.) $\operatorname{tr}_{K_{{{p}^{{m}_{n+t}}}}/K_{{p}^{{m}_{n+t-1}}}}{\alpha}_{n+t}={f}_{n}{\alpha}_{n}+T_{n},$

where $T_{n}$ is torsion of order prime to $p(p^2-1)$, and $\nu_{p}(f_{n})=0$, where ${\nu}_{p}$ denotes the valuation at $p$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A(K_{p^n})$ are all finitely generated? Otherwise you could just have $A(L)=A(K_{p^1})$ and the answer is "no".

Comment: Correct. Edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the answer is "no". If you take an elliptic curve with supersingular reduction at $p$, $K$ a sufficiently carefully chosen imaginary quadratic field, and $L / K$ the anticyclotomic $\mathbf{Z}_p$-extension, then you can rig things so that $E(L)$ is not finitely generated, because there are non-torsion Heegner points for all but finitely many of the characters of $L / K$.  But these can't be massaged into a trace-compatible sequence, and in fact no such trace-compatible sequence exists, because of $E$ being supersingular.

Comment: Correct. I have edited the question now. (The case t=2 deals with the supersingular counterexample.)

Comment: Your "fix" of allowing more general $t$ will only work when $a_p = 0$. So it will not work for supersingular elliptic curves with $a_p \ne 0$ (which can happen when $p = 2$ or $p = 3$), and there are many more possibilities for modular abelian varieties of larger dimension.

Comment: To put it bluntly: do you have any reason to expect such sequences should exist, other than "it would be nice if..."? It is true that in the tiny handful of known examples of $\mathbf{Z}_p$-extensions where one obtains systematic rank growth, this comes from trace-compatible sequences. But this is because rank growth is rare, not because trace-compatible sequences are common! The existence of these compatible sequences is an extremely deep and hard theorem, it's not just a formal consequence of $A(L)$ being infinitely-generated.

Comment: I think it's still an interesting question to ask, even if the conditions need to be modified (as I agree that the sequence is unlikely to exist in general). Heuristically at least, and subject to various standard/folklore conjectures, one could try to reformulate it (very speculatively) in terms of L-values -- namely central derivative values of self-dual GL(2)*GL(2) Rankin-Selberg L-functions in families with symmetric functional equation(s), where much of the anticyclotomic phenomena is expected (i.e. conjectured) to carry over granted special/generic conditions on the root number(s).

Comment: @jvo That's kind of what I meant by "rank growth is rare". I've heard the view expressed (by Coates among others) that Selmer ranks, MW ranks, etc should always be bounded in towers when they're not forced to be large by root number phenomena. When there are root number phenomena forcing systematic vanishing of L-values, then it's reasonable to expect some sort of Heegner-like trace-compatible sequences of points, but this is very much deeper than being a mere formal consequence of the algebraic setup as the original question seems to propose.

Comment: @ David Loeffler: Agreed! People working in the analytic theory of automorphic forms have completely analogous intuition here concerning vanishing/nonvanishing behaviour. What I am proposing is not a solution to the problem of course, but rather a source of intuition. And while it is rare, I suppose it is not obvious that Heegner-like growth should necessarily be confined to the CM setting in this framework.